# status code 304 not modified, but file was modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have cleared the browser cache, and have restarted the browser, but Chrome still returns `304` code.

How do I make IIS return `200` code?

[image: this css file have modified]

request respond details:

[image]

Comment: Try Shift-F5 or Shift+Command+R

Comment: @DarinDimitrov not working? what's the diffrent between ctrl+f5 & f5 ??will that clear cache or something??? I think it caused by iis, not broswer

Comment: @BijoyThangaraj not working what's that??

Comment: @Kevin: That is one-time cache refresh. Check here:
http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the status you're getting is most likely a result of the two headers at the bottom of your screenshot: `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match`.  These are detailed [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

Basically, these headers say to the server that if the conditions in the header are met, send the resource (with a `200` response).  If the conditions are not met, send a `304` response.  So, IIS thinks that the file has not been modified since 25 June and that its etag is the value in the `if-none-match` header.

There could be a number of reasons for this depending on your IIS configuration and what, exactly, is being served.  Firefox is likely working because it's *not* sending those headers.

Comment: had the same problem so here's an addition to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294034/chrome-browser-is-not-sending-if-modified-since-header-to-server

Comment: But if the file has been modified, as his title suggests, and assuming it is before 25 June, then should it not still be re-served?

Comment: @Asken: Good reference!  This could be the opposite problem, but the solution is still the right one :-)

Comment: @JustinHarvey: If the file's been modified *or* it's after 25 June, I would hope that it would be served.  Indeed, the spec I linked to does state that "If any of the entity tags match [that defined in If-None-Match] ... the server MUST NOT perform the requested method, unless ... the resource's modification date fails to match that supplied in an If-Modified-Since header field in the request"

Comment: @JustinHarvey: also, the reason for my slight vagueness in the last question is that it's possible to handle those headers in-code (that is, overriding standard IIS behaviours).  It's easy enough to write a handler that will ignore them entirely and always/never re-serve.  I didn't want to assume that the OP is just serving files out of vanilla IIS...

Comment: @Dan Puzey, yep, I'm aware of that as I have just written one.  I wondered if you have any comment on 'By definition the 304 is coming from IIS; it's a server response', as I was fairly sure that the browser shows this for files it serves from its cache too.

Comment: @JustinHarvey: We can't control what a browser displays in its own logs, but if the browser shows "HTTP Status 304" for something that hasn't been requested from the server, I'd say that's misleading.  Sadly I'm not a heavy Chrome user so I can't comment on its behaviour!

Comment: @Dan Puzey, see comment to my answer above, I think you have to be careful about how you interpret what the browser might be telling you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the 304 is coming from IIS.  You can check this using a tool, such as fiddler.

Try an IISReset to see if that helps.

Comment: By definition the 304 is coming from IIS; it's a server response.  IISReset is a reasonable idea but is only a workaround - it won't stop the problem recurring.

Comment: As I understaood it, it is possible to see 304 when no call is made to the server, i.e. when the browser serves from its cache.

Comment: A 304 status means that the current modified date/etag of the resource matches those in the headers you sent, so there's no value in downloading again - but it's the server that sends that status (unless you have an active proxy/cache in between).  When a browser serves from its own (internal) cache *without* hitting the server, there is no response code because no request is made. This is different to "requesting a resource but allowing the server to tell you whether your cache is still up to date."

Comment: @Dan Puzey, I was really trying to make the point clear, that Internet Explorer, for example, will report a 304 in its network log for pages that it has served from its cache.  I have verified this by refreshing a page I am developing and seeing around 300 '304's in the browser, but only around 20 in Fiddler that actually go out to IIS.

Comment: you may be right.  Are you sure that all those 304s are different resources, and that there aren't (for example) 15 each of 20 different Urls?  That might explain the lower number of requests.

Comment: Oh yes, they are definitely different resources, many separate .js files in this example.