# Does Chrome violate the standards in caching?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, caching

We noticed Chrome caches files locally and doesn't even send a request to our server to check if there's a newer version of the javascript file.

Example of HTTP response headers for a js file that Google cached:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:5479
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Tue, 12 Jan 2016 22:46:07 GMT
ETag:"7d68e1ceb647d11:0"
Last-Modified:Tue, 05 Jan 2016 12:44:25 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
x-robots-tag:noindex
```

Is it valid that Chrome cached the file? There's no `Cache-control` header or something that declares that the file can be cached locally, it only has ETag and Last-Modified.

---

**BTW**

Is there a way (maybe a header) to instruct Chrome to check if the cached file has changed **without appending version to the file name**? Setting no-cache is not an option since I do want it to be cached, but I want to use the ETag and Last-Modified headers as it should.

Comment: I'm not answering the main question but do you know of this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/704097

Comment: Also possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294034/chrome-browser-is-not-sending-if-modified-since-header-to-server

Comment: @Miquel, yes I'm aware of that option in the dev tools. But I can't nor want my users to use it and clear the entire cache of my site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unless specifically constrained by a cache-control (section 14.9)
>   directive, a caching system MAY always store a successful response
>   (see section 13.8) as a cache entry, MAY return it without validation
>   if it is fresh, and MAY return it after successful validation.

You can always use the must-revalidate directive.

> When the must-revalidate directive is present in a response received
>   by a cache, that cache MUST NOT use the entry after it becomes stale
>   to respond to a subsequent request without first revalidating it with
>   the origin server.

[Source](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.4)

Comment: Hmm... I'm curious to know why you stopped quoting just before the spec says it's expected for caches not to cache responses where there is no indication that the response can be cached. "_If there is neither a cache validator nor an explicit expiration time associated with a response, we do not expect it to be cached, but certain caches MAY violate this expectation_"